# Bash script that automatically uploads to s3 after build

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, sh, sbt-assembly

I want to write a bash script that builds with `sbt assembly` my scala code and pushes my jar automatically to an s3 bucket.
What I did is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
sbt assembly &&
aws s3 cp target/scala-2.11/monthly_table_updater-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar s3://my-bucket/monthly_table_updater/
```

The problem with this is if I wanted to change my package name I'd also need to change it in the bash script.

This is the final output of `sbt assembly`:

```
[info] Assembly up to date: /home/user/Projects/monthly_table_updater/target/scala-2.11/monthly_table_updater-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Perhaps getting the last part of this output and passing it to the next command could be a solution, however I am not so practical with linux. command.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: There would obviously be a way to easily parse it through `sed`, `grep` or `awk`. Can you just update your question to contain samples of which command generates the output, how the output looks and how to you want to use it.

Comment: I think I found the most important peace of the output: `[info] Assembly up to date: /home/simone/Projects/monthly_table_updater/target/scala-2.11/monthly_table_updater-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` maybe by getting the last part could be possible to pass it to the next command